# Use of "was drowned"

Tags: word-usage

In chapter four of The Great Gatsby, Nick Carraway gives a list of people who attended Gatsby's parties.  He mentions a Doctor Civet:

> *...and Doctor Civet who **was drowned** last summer up in Maine.*

I'm interested in the use of "was drowned."  From my understanding, "was drowned" is the passive and implies an agent.  However, to drown someone is somewhat violent, and from my point of view doesn't seem to fit.

Is "was drowned" an older expression for "drowned?"  In other words, in more current vernacular we might say "He drowned while swimming." and an accidental death is implied because no one murdered the person directly.  If the person was murdered, we would say "He was drowned while swimming."

Comment: You're over-analyzing.  Sometimes a drowning is just a drowning.

Comment: I think it may refer to the waters, the sea, which "drowned" the person. "*Gânth's daughter threw her into deep water and she was drowned*." https://books.google.it/books?id=DmyVKwxmeyUC&pg=PA301&dq=%22she+was+drowned%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE2tql6MLKAhXKliwKHa-lAnEQ6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=%22she%20was%20drowned%22&f=false ***Ngram: he/she was drowned:*** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+drowned%2C+she+was+drowned&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20was%20drowned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20was%20drowned%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 that's what I was thinking also...that he was drowned by the lake or ocean...but I'm not sure because nowadays people would say "he drowned."

Comment: Checking with Ngram, *he drowned vs he was drowned*, the former is more common now. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+drowned%2C+he+drowned+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20was%20drowned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20drowned%3B%2Cc0, but I think the meaning is the same and "was drowned" does not necessarily imply a killer.

Comment: @Josh61 interesting then that the passive was preferred.

Comment: From the ***OED*** : 3. a. To suffocate (a person or animal) by submersion in water (or other liquid).
Mostly with personal agent, ***or reflexive or passive; but also said of the action of the water.***
 ***1300*** Cursor M. 1652, I sal þam alle in watur droun [v. rr. drenkil, drenche]. -  ***1847*** Tennyson Princ. Prol. 47 Part were drown'd within the whirling brook -

Comment: @Josh61 ok, so the passive was preferred at one time, whereas more recently the active is preferred.  So, no one killed Civet.

Comment: I'd need to know about the context, but it sounds like he just drowned.

Comment: @Josh61 the context is what I gave.  Interestingly, in chapter 6, Civet is talking to miss Baedeker who says "They almost drowned me once."  She was talking about some people who stuck her head in a pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Oald says "to drown can be used as transitive verb (1 to drown someone), and it can be used as intransitive verb with no object (2 The children drowned in the lake).
It is a special and idiomatic quirk of English that for intransive to drown you can find a passive form (3 The children were drowned in the lake). But this passive form is not meant as a real passive, it has the same meaning as 2.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/drown?q=drown

Actually I don't know how this curious expression came about. Etymonline mentions to be drowned, but has no explanation for the curious passive form.
(German is very clear in this respect, ertrinken is intransitive with no object, ertränken is transitive.)

Obviously speakers and writers feel that 3 is a bit queer and prefer nowadays 2.

Comment: Please delineate actual "quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a murder would have been passively added by Fitzgerald.  Pretty sure "drowned" and "was drowned" are interchangeable here, although it is weird wording.